# Get html rendered by Javascript using PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, html, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am trying to utilize PhantomJS to get html generated by dynamic page. I supposed that this would be easy, but after few hours of trying, I am still not lucky.

The page itself has this source code and what gets saved in 1.html eventually:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="cs" ng-app="appId">
<head ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     (ommited some lines)
    <script src="/js/conf/config.js?pars"></script>
    <script src="/js/all.js?pars"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--<![endif]-->
    <div site-loader></div>
    <div page-layout>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

All content of web gets loaded inside site-loader div, but I have no luck to get it, even though I am using timeout before scraping html by PhantomJS. Here goes code I am using:

```
var url = 'http:...';
var page = require('webpage').create();
var fs = require('fs');

page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Fail');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {        
        window.setTimeout(function () {
        fs.write('1.html', page.content, 'w');
        phantom.exit();
        }, 2000); // Change timeout as required to allow sufficient time 
    }
});
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
I have decided to try PJscrapper framework and configured it to scrappe all contents of div block. All I got was lousy:

```
["","\n\t\tif (window.DOT) {\n\t\t\tDOT.cfg({service: 'sreality', impress: false});\n\t\t}\n\t","","Loader.load()","",""]
```

Seems that I seriously do not get it and always get code before Loader.load() acts. And obviously, timeout does not solve it.

Comment: You didn't show what is written to `1.html`. Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#webpage-onConsoleMessage) and [`onError`](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference-WebPage#onerror) events. Maybe there are errors. If bind is an issue, you need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521).

Comment: Hi, in the resulting 1.html is the same code as I have put into my question (html). This is the same code as is shown when I hit Ctrl+U in browser. But my understanding, that this get manipulated by Java Script somehow. Becasuse when I manualy inspect elements of page, I can see them in mentioned div block... I will check the onError event and see what will happen, thanks for your help.

Comment: When I registered onError as you have mentioned I am getting two errors for missing variables: ERROR: ReferenceError: Cant find variable. One variable is named Loader and another JAK (both can be found in JavaScript generating page. Am I doing something principially wrong?

Comment: As a couple more troubleshooting ideas: 1. Try your script with SlimerJS. This uses a different rendering engine. If the results are different, maybe it is something not supported in PhantomJS 1.9. 2. ALso do `page.render` so you can see a screenshot. Is it dull, or does it look like the page you see in your own browser?

Comment: Thanks for ideas, I will try SlimerJS - but right now I am getting 'Fail' - which means that `page.open(url, function (status)` resulted into status different than `success`. When I did screenshot, it is dull...

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick

```
    page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the url!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            var results = page.evaluate(function() {
                return document.documentElement.innerHTML;
            });
            console.log(results)
            phantom.exit();
        }, 200);
    }
});
```